# which vs what in a sentence, is what possible to use?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I wonder if I can use "what" while writing a formal text. Here is an example: "He didn't mind marrying another woman which/what was illegal" (I want to say that the act of marrying was illegal, not the woman). When "what" is used the sentence seems to be far more clear but is it even possible to use "what"?

Comment: No, it isn't. If you had meant the woman you would have had to use _who_.

Comment: So using "what" in any other similar case is grammatically incorrect? I heard that it is possible to use "what" in some dialects. Thank you!